# Using other file names than models.py for Django models?

Tags: python, django, model

When creating a reusable app, should I put all models I define into single file `models.py` or can I group the models into several files like `topic1.py`, `topic2.py`?

Please describe all reasons pro and contra.

Answer (score 4):

The `models` submodule is special in that it is automatically imported at a specific time during the initialization process. All your models should be imported at this time as well. You can't import them earlier than that, and importing them later may cause errors.

You can define your models in a different module, but you should always import all your models into your `models.py` or `models/__init__.py`. E.g.:

```
# models/topic1.py

class Topic1(models.Model):
    ...

# models/__init__.py

from .topic1 import Topic1
```

If you import each model into `models.py` or `models/__init__.py`, that also allows you to import all the models directly from that file. In the example, that means that you can import `Topic1` from `myapp.models`, not just from `myapp.models.topic1`. This way you can keep your models organized across multiple files without having to remember each model's precise location whenever you need to import them.

Comment: Are models in `models/` automatically imported? (with empty `__init__.py`)

Comment: Only the `models` module is loaded. As is standard in python, that means only the `__init__.py` file is actually loaded. To load other files in the `models/` directory you need to import them individually.

Answer (score 0):

it depend how much model you define, if you have only 1 to 5 class model, just put it into single file, but if you have more than 5 class model, i suggesting put it on several files,

but in my experience, if the model put in a serveral files, it become little cumbersome when it comes to importing stuff,

Comment: but they all should be in `models/` dir for Django to find them, right? or no?

Comment: yes, and one thing you should import the class models not files,

for example,
from app.models.topic_one import ModelClass

note : use snake_case for file module, and FirstCase for Class Model, it will help you when it comes to importing stuff.